# Guice wrap generic injections

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Is it possible to wrap generic injections in some way?

Given the interface:

`interface IFoo<T>`

In my guice module:

`bind((Key<IFoo<SomeType>) Key.get(Types.newParameterizedType(IFoo.class, SomeType.class))).to(Foo.class);`

But before I return the Foo instance I want to wrap it with this:

`class FooWrapper<T> implements IFoo<T> { public FooWrapper(Foo<T> foo) { ... } }`

Somewhere like this:

`return new FooWrapper<T>(foo);`

Comment: Why the complicated stuff with `Key.get` rather than `bind(new TypeLiteral<IFoo<SomeType>>(){}).to(...)`?

Comment: Using Key.get instead of TypeLiteral lets you export most of your bloat to methods like this: `public static <T extends Model<T>> Key<ModelService<T>> modelService(Class<T> t) {
  return (Key<ModelService<T>>) Key.get(Types.newParameterizedType(ModelService.class, t));
 }`

Comment: Then you just `bind(modelService(SomeModelService.class)).to(SomeImplemenration.class);`. It's all aesthetic really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you can do this:

```
public class FooModule extends PrivateModule {
  @Retention(RUNTIME) @BindingAnnotation
  private @interface Internal {}

  @Override protected void configure() {
    bind(new TypeLiteral<IFoo<SomeType>>(){}).annotatedWith(Internal.class)
        .to(new TypeLiteral<Foo<SomeType>>(){});
  }

  @Provides @Exposed IFoo<SomeType> provideFoo(@Internal IFoo<SomeType> foo) {
    return new FooWrapper<SomeType>(foo);
  }
}
```

Another thing that might work well would be to add a general annotation like `@Wrapped` and then to declare `FooWrapper`'s constructor like this:

```
@Inject public FooWrapper(@Wrapped IFoo<T> foo) { ... }
```

Then in your private module you could bind `Foo` annotated with `@Wrapped` and bind and expose `FooWrapper` normally, without needing to use an `@Provides` method.

There may well be better ways of doing this I haven't thought of yet. Do also keep in mind that method interception is often a good way of decorating interface implementations with other behavior as well.

Comment: Your answer is correct for my original question, but I realised I should have given more information as it does not solve my problem. Unfortunately you can't use .annotatedWith on a bound Key. Any ideas?

Comment: Ignore that comment, I just realised you need to give the annotation class inside Key.get as the second parameter.

Comment: @Finbarr: I updated my answer to match your edits to the question, though I used `TypeLiteral` rather than `Key`... but yes, annotations are part of the `Key`.